# Pandas dropping duplicates doesn't drop last duplicate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, duplicates

Setting keep=False should remove all duplicates but if I run my function is still returns a duplicate of the previous row

```
def date_to_csv():
   import pandas as pd
   from random import randint
   df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
   df = df.append({'Date': datetime.date.today(), 'Price': randint(1,100)}, ignore_index=True)
   result_df = df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
   result_df.to_csv('test.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=None)
```

If my csv file is empty with only the column headers 'Date' and 'Price' and I run my function 3 times it returns this in csv:

```
Date,Price
2021-06-26,74
2021-06-26,74
2021-06-26,51
2021-06-26,51
2021-06-26,13
```

When I expect it to return something like this:

```
Date,Price
2021-06-26,74
2021-06-26,51
2021-06-26,13
```

Comment: Are there other fields in your test.csv?

Comment: only the two column headers 'Date' and 'Price'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of `mode='a'` you can't remove previous duplicates after several execution of your function. Here is a code for your expected behaviour:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


def date_to_csv(): 
     df = pd.read_csv('test.csv') 
     df = df.append({'Date': str(datetime.now().date()), 'Price': randint(1, 100)}, ignore_index=True) 
     df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Also the last `Date` value is a datetime object, the previous ones are strings.